# How can I use the solutions of coupled nonlinear equations as functions of its parameters?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I have a set of coupled nonlinear equations.
I want to plot all the possible solutions as functions of the parameter AA.
I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
xsol[AA_] := x /. Solve[{ x^2 - 5 x + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}]; 
ysol[AA_] := y /. Solve[{ x^2 - 5 x + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}];
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: xsol[AA_] := x /. Solve[{ x^2 - 5 x  + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}];

Comment: ysol[AA_] := y /. Solve[{ x^2 - 5 x  + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}];

Comment: Paul You can edit your question (e.g. to add code) using the "edit" link on the bottom left of the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach:

```
sol = Solve[{x^2 - 5 x + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x, y} /. sol], {AA, 0, 25/24}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = Values@Solve[{x^2 - 5 x + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}] // 
   Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
Plot[sol, {AA, -6, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First you can define your functions as

```
(*here i ranges from 1 to 6*)
xsol[i_][t_]:=Part[(x/.Solve[{x^2-5x+6 AA == 0, y^3 -AA x^2 ==0}])/.AA->t, i]

ysol[i_][t_]:=Part[(x/.Solve[{x^2-5x+6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 ==0},{x,y}])/.AA->t, i]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[xsol[i][t], {i,1,6}]],{t,-2,2}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[ysol[i][t],{i,1,6}]],{t,-2,2}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have to be a little careful here. Since the equations are quadratic in `x` and cubic in `y`, `Solve` will return six solution pairs for `x` and `y`. But not all the solutions will produce real-valued functions over the parameter `AA`, In fact, there are only two unique solutions for `x`. For `y` there are six different solutions, but two them are only real-valued at `AA = 0`, and it is not meaningful to plot them.

To see that this is the case, let us look at solution of the system of equations in some detail.

```
sol = Solve[{x^2 - 5 x + 6 AA == 0, y^3 - AA x^2 == 0}, {x, y}]
```

[image: solution]

By inspection, we can see that there are just two unique solutions for `x`, so we define 
`xsol` as:

```
xsol[AA_] = (sol[[All, 1, 2]] // DeleteDuplicates)
```

> ```
> {1/2 (5 - Sqrt[25 - 24 AA]), 1/2 (5 + Sqrt[25 - 24 AA])}
> ```

Now let's look at the solutions for `y`. Because the 1st solution for `y` is

> ```
> -(-(1/2))^(1/3) (25 AA - 5 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 12 AA^2)^(1/3)
> ```

and

```
ReIm[-(-(1/2))^(1/3)]
Reduce[Im[(25 AA - 5 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 12 AA^2)^(1/3)] == 0, AA, Reals]
```

give

> ```
> {-(1/(2 2^(1/3))), -(Sqrt[3]/(2 2^(1/3)))}  
> 0 <= AA <= 25/24
> ```

respectively, we can conclude that the 1st solution for `y` is real only when `AA == 0`. So there is no curve to plot for this solution. A similar argument can be made for the 5th solution for `y`. So we define `ysol` as:

```
ysol[AA_] = sol[[{2, 3, 4, 6}, 2, 2]]
```

> ```
> {(25 AA - 5 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 12 AA^2)^(1/3)/2^(1/3), 
>  ((-1)^(2/3) (25 AA - 5 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 12 AA^2)^(1/3))/2^(1/3), 
>  ((25 AA)/2 + 5/2 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 6 AA^2)^(1/3), 
>  (-1)^(2/3) ((25 AA)/2 + 5/2 Sqrt[25 - 24 AA] AA - 6 AA^2)^(1/3)}
> ```

With these definitions for `xsol` and `ysol`, the plots can be made with:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ xsol[AA], {AA, -1, 25/24}, PlotLegends -> {1, 4}]
```

[image: xplot]

```
Plot[Evaluate @ ysol[AA], {AA, -1, 25/24}, PlotLegends -> {2, 3, 4, 6}]
```

[image: yplot]